# SoundCloud: play button

Tags: jquery, soundcloud

I just want a play and stop button to substitute the original ones in SoundCloud. I followed the "Widget API" : http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#
But it doen't work. I think I don't understand very well the SoundCloud instructions to do that.

I have it here playing:
http://jsfiddle.net/wBTCh/1/

HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script>

    <iframe id="so" width="100%" height="160" scrolling="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/users/1539950/favorites" frameborder="0" ></iframe>

    <div id="playSound"></div>
    <div id="stopSound"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#so{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}

#playSound{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#stopSound{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY:

```
$(function(){

    var iframeElement   = document.querySelector('iframe');
    var iframeElementID = iframeElement.id;
    var widget1         = SC.Widget("#so");
    var widget2         = SC.Widget("#so");
    // widget1 === widget2

    $("#playSound").click(function() {
        $("#so").play()
    });

    $("#stopSound").click(function() {
        $("#so").pause()
    });

})
```

Comment: Sorry, but: Where exactly is your problem and what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I see a play button and a pause button, you might be using an old browser. As for a stop button I have looked over the docs a little and I cannot find mention of adding one, so...yea dunno what else I can say

Comment: Ok I see what your trying to do now and I don't think you have done as the doc tells you. You have to add a script to your page as it says above then you need to initialise the script with `var w = SC.Widget($('#so').get());` then to play the video from the event, `w.play()`

Comment: Or actually you can just do `var w = SC.Widget('#so');` for the SC.Widget thing. So yea you have to include the script as it tells you to at the top of your page, the script can be found here: http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js and once you have that script ihncluded you can use it to control the iframe.

Comment: I added this in the head: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script> But I'm not sure if this is the way to do it. On the other hand I added the vars but I don't understand them. I tried all here, and It doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/wBTCh/1/

Comment: Sebanstian: I try to do a simple play and stop button to substitute the player in SoundCloud. I follow the instructions on their web but I don't understand it very well and I ask for help to adapt that instructions to my very simple case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok this is working for me:

JS:

```
var widget1 = SC.Widget("so");

$(function(){
    $("#playSound").click(function() {
        widget1.play();

    });

    $("#stopSound").click(function() {
        widget1.pause()
    });
})
```

Html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script>

<iframe id="so" width="100%" height="160" scrolling="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/users/1539950/favorites" frameborder="0" ></iframe>

<div id="playSound"></div>
<div id="stopSound"></div>
```

It now correctly controls the iframe player.

This is the full working example from JSBin:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <head>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>


   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- SoundCloud-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    $(function(){
      var widget1 = SC.Widget("so");

        $("#playSound").click(function() {
          widget1.play();

      });  
      $("#stopSound").click(function() {
          widget1.pause();
      });      
    });
  </script> 


  <style type="text/css">
  <!--

  #so{
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      left: 20px;
  }

  #playSound{
      position: absolute;
      top: 200px;
      left: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: blue;
  }

  #stopSound{
      position: absolute;
      top: 200px;
      left: 50px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: green;
  }
  ​

  -->
  </style>
 </head>

<body>

<iframe id="so" width="100%" height="160" scrolling="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/users/1539950/favorites" frameborder="0" ></iframe>

<div id="playSound"></div>
<div id="stopSound"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works!. I still don't understand how did you get that from the instructions of SoundCloud.  

I try it here and it works perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/wBTCh/2/

But when I copy paste in Dreamweaver it doesn't work. I don't understand why. So I tried JSBin. Because it shows all the code together: http://jsbin.com/usoxek/1/edit Any idea where could be the problem?

Comment: @Narcís Ok I have fixed the version you gave in JSBin, it is because the iframe was not being assigned when the document had fully loaded so the JS was just being run without the contents of the iframe being ready, tbh kinda sucky programming on SoundClouds part but I guess ease of use and all.

Comment: Ok perfect. Here I leave the example in JSBin. If someone needs to see it working: http://jsbin.com/usoxek/5/edit Thank you very much!